# SceneKit init DAE model crash only on iOS9 device

Tags: ios, crash, ios9, scenekit

my APP runs a dae file model with SceneKit, display on a SceneView. From iOS8.0 to 8.4 everything goes well, init it as below:

```
SCNScene *myScene;
NSString *scenePath = [cachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mymodel.dae"];
NSURL *curSCNUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:scenePath];
SCNScene *myScene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL:curSCNUrl options:nil error:nil];
```

BUT, recently i updated to iOS9, Xcode7.0.1, the same code crash at SCNScene sceneWithURL:options:error:, only crash on iphone device not simulator && on iOS9.
on simulator ios8 & ios9 goes well. on iphone device ios8 goes well.
stack info as below pic.

```
[SCNScene sceneWithURL:curSCNUrl options:nil error:nil];
```

i found someone said, maybe its the metal and GL problem, and i insert the options when SceneView init. still crash on iphone with ios9.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{SCNPreferredRenderingAPIKey: @(SCNRenderingAPIOpenGLES2)};
self = [super initWithFrame:frame options:options];
```

Have someone met this situation? pls give me some solution or advice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5slM6.jpg)